# link_to external URL treated as internal despite starting with http:// (Rails 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I'm using

```
link_to "Click Here", "http://www.cnn.com"
```

and its producing a link with the following href

```
"localhost:3000http://www.cnn.com"
```

For some reason, it's not recognizing the `http://` as indicating an external URL, and treating it as a relative URL.

I tried going to the source of [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and copied it into my application helper. I found that the `.html_safe` was doing the transformation, because when I pulled it out, it worked as expected.

I can't figure out which `html_safe` its using. When I copied in the source of [HAML:Util.html_safe](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Util.html#html_safe-instance_method) it also worked fine. Therefore, I assume the `html_safe` that `link_to` is using is resolving to something else, even though the view is a Haml file.

Based on what I see in the Haml method, it seems that `html_safe` calls `html_safe!` to transform the string when it thinks its unsafe.

I'm using the normal American English/Latin character set, so I don't see why it's not parsing the `http://` correctly

I'm using Rails 2.3.5.

For now, I plan to hand-code the href into my view to avoid calling `link_to` for the external link, but if anyone can help me figure out what is going on, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Small point. Don't use "click here" Its not descriptive or helpful in anyway

Comment: I wouldn't use dynamic link creation for static links; it's always slower.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to reproduce this behavior, but it sounds like a bug. Also please note that Rails 2.3.5 is quite old. I believe the current 2.3.x version is 2.3.12.

As a side note, the API docs you're referring to are for Rails 3.1.3. So you won't be able to obtain useful 2.3.5 debugging info from those docs. The easiest way to read the source that's actually in use in your app is to look in the gems folder on your development machine.

Anyhow, there's definitely nothing wrong with hand-coding the `<a>` tag like you're doing. In fact, it's slightly more efficient, as it avoids executing the Ruby code in `link_to`. So, it may actually be best just to keep doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem within an ERB file, my problem was solved when I used instead of an quoted an unquoted link and called html_safe afterwards. Maybe your problem will be safed too.